# Call Waiting with At Command - Telit le910 v2

Tags: at-command, telit

I try to activate call waiting for telit le910, but when I sent this commands, I got error response. If I insert the sim card into my phone and dial *43# it is activeted. Do you have any suggestions for solution? How can I activate this feature with AT commands?

at+ccwa=1,1,7
+CME ERROR: operation not supported

at+ccwa=1,1,1
+CME ERROR: operation not supported

Comment: What is the response to `AT+CCWA=?` command? Is `AT+CCWA` present in the response of `AT+CLAC` command?

Comment: Response to AT+CCWA=? command is like that.
+CCWA: (0,1)
OK

Response to AT+CCWA=1 command is like that.
OK

Response to AT+CCWA? command is like that.
+CCWA: 1

OK

Comment: I think, we can just enables/disables the presentation of an unsolicited result code with AT+CCWA command.

Comment: Yes: apparently only the first parameter is supported.

Comment: But, If I insert the sim card into my phone and dial *43# it is activeted. Can I do that with AT commands? I can't always plug and unplug the sim card from the phone. It would be a complete torture for a lot of sim cards.